# Use modalbox for delete confirmation in place of alert in cakephp2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I baked a cakephp project where i want to use nifty-modalbox for delete confirmation in place of normal alert. Anyone have idea how to do that.

Here is the scenario:
Bootstrap 3
jquery.niftymodals.js

Here is the desired html code.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-mono2 btn-flat md-trigger" data-modal="dark-primary">Delete</a>
<!-- Nifty Modal -->
                <div class="md-modal md-dark md-effect-3" id="dark-primary">
                    <div class="md-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3>Custom Header Color</h3>
                        <button type="button" class="close md-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="text-center">
                          <h4><strong>Awesome!</strong></h4>
                          <h5>Can you say supercalifragilisticoexpialidoso?</h5>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mono2 btn-flat md-close" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mono2 btn-flat md-close" data-dismiss="modal">Proceed</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Cakephp code:

```
<?php   echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $post['Post']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
```

Can anyone suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cakePHP for this you can create [your own helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers), and let it extend FormHelper. Then you override the [postLink method](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink) and tailor it after your needs. The file you want to be looking for is [Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-FormHelper.html#21-2877). This is the current cakePHP implementation for the confirmation dialog (starts at line 1786):

```
if ($confirmMessage) {
            $confirmMessage = str_replace(array("'", '"'), array("\'", '\"'), $confirmMessage);
            $options['onclick'] = "if (confirm('{$confirmMessage}')) { {$onClick} }";
}
```

Good luck!